# Quotation mark and slash mark in C# string

Tags: c#, string, quotation-marks

I want to execute a cmd command in C#. Below command AAA is working in Windows 10 cmd. The below code's string AAA part is not the correct format in C#. How can I change this cmd command into correct C# string format?

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            string AAA= "curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" -d "@xxx.json" "https://some.org/api/oauth/token"";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = AAA;
```

Comment: Doesn't the syntax highlighting help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `@` in front of the string and use double qoutes.

```
string AAA = @"curl -X POST --header ""Content-Type: application/json"" --header ""Accept: application/json"" -d ""@xxx.json"" ""https://some.org/api/oauth/token""";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the escape using backslash `\` before quote char `"`. Use the below code.

```
string AAA = "curl -X POST --header \"Content-Type: application/json\" --header \"Accept: application/json\" -d \"@xxx.json\" \"https://some.org/api/oauth/token\"";
```

Check the fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kfz4ca

Comment: See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/escape-sequences?view=msvc-160) for more information about escape characters

Answer (score 1):

```
string AAA = @"curl -X POST --header ""Content - Type: application / json""--header ""Accept: application / json"" - d ""@xxx.json"" ""https://some.org/api/oauth/token""";
```